# Is this Swing behavior a bug? Mysterious BoxLayout alignment

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, layout-manager, boxlayout

I've been playing around with [WindowBuilder Pro](https://developers.google.com/java-dev-tools/wbpro/) for Java Swing layouts, and encountered some strange behavior that I was eventually able to reduce down to a SSCCE.  Consider the source code below:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;

import javax.swing.BoxLayout;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class WBPTest2 {
    private JFrame frame;
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    WBPTest2 window = new WBPTest2();
                    window.frame.setVisible(true);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }
    public WBPTest2() {
        initialize();
    }
    private void initialize() {
        frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setBounds(100, 100, 450, 300);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        panel.setBackground(Color.RED);
        frame.getContentPane().add(panel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        panel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(panel, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));

        JPanel panel_1 = new JPanel();
        panel_1.setBackground(Color.GREEN);
        panel_1.setMaximumSize(new Dimension(32767, 100));
        panel.add(panel_1);
        panel_1.setLayout(new BoxLayout(panel_1, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));

        JPanel panel_2 = new JPanel();
        panel_2.setBackground(Color.BLUE);
        panel_2.setMaximumSize(new Dimension(32767, 100));
        panel.add(panel_2);
        panel_2.setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.CENTER, 5, 5));
    }
}
```

It gives the following layout:

[image]

For whatever reason, `panel_1`, the green one, floats to the right.  Playing with some of the parameters in the code, I can only find two ways to completely kill the gap to the left of the green panel:

- change the `hgap` and `vgap` in the `panel_2` constructor to 0.

OR

- change the `minimumSize` of `panel_2` to (0,0).

Do either of those, and we get this:

[image]

Now, the question is, why on earth would either the `minimumSize` or the `hgap` for the `FlowLayout` in `panel_2` have anything to do with preventing `panel_1` from filling all the way to the left of its parent?  What if I happened to want a `minimumSize` greater than zero, and an `hgap` greater than zero, for my `FlowLayout` in `panel_2`?  How then would I eliminate the gap to the left of my `BoxLayout` in `panel_1`?

No matter **what** I do to `panel_1`, I cannot make it fill the whole width of its parent container (unless I edit `panel_2` as described above).  Ironically, if I set the `alignmentX` for `panel_1` to `RIGHT_ALIGNMENT`, it actually floats to the left.  But the gap still exists (just now on the right).  As I fill `panel_1` with content and increase its size, the gap to its right grows smaller and smaller, but never completely goes away, frustratingly.

This doesn't just happen when `panel_2` is a `FlowLayout`... it also happens with `JScrollPane` and many other types... types which don't usually have the `hgap` parameter, which means the only way to fix the gap to the left of `panel_1` is to change the new container's `minimumSize` to 0, which again seems silly and unrelated, and most importantly may not be my design intent.

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).  *"that I was eventually able to reduce down to a SSCCE."*  Umm.. good.  Will you eventually share that SSCCE?

Comment: @AndrewThompson Sorry, guess I misunderstood SSCCE and thought main method was enough.  Here is the entire source code attached now.  Thanks.

Comment: @AndrewThompson What do you mean by `null` layout?  [Oracle tutorials](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html#border) say "Every content pane is initialized to use a BorderLayout." So I believe my `frame` layout is not null?  Just for grins I did try explicitly changing it to `BorderLayout` by a constructor, and it still runs the same.  Also, I'm not sure I understand what you are suggesting with the `BufferedImage`, sorry.

Comment: I set alignmentX on panels 1 and 2 and it fills the screen.

Comment: @BevynQ Thank you, that does seem to solve it.  Post it as an answer and I'll accept it. :-)  Don't know how I missed that.  Still, it seems odd that two center alignments add up to one of the elements being right aligned, but whatever.

Comment: @The111 My bad.  I misread the question.  :P

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set alignmentX on panels 1 and 2 and it fills the screen.

It appears the two different layout managers cause the panel to set different alignment defaults.